# How can $x=4$ in $x/2+2=x$, when I solve I get $x=2$, but in the equation, $x=4$ also works

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't know how to solve for $x$ to get $x$ equal to $4$ for the equation $x/2+2=x$. When I solve the equation I keep getting $x=2$, which works, but so does the equation when $x=4$. How can I can the equation to get $x=4$?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently it's because your solution is wrong; unless you include it here, we won't be able to point out where the error is (and note that $x = 2$ does not work).

Answer (score 2):

$x=2$ is not a solution.

We have $$\frac{x}{2}+2=x$$

so subtracting $x/2$ from both sides we have $$2=\frac{x}{2}$$

and thus $x=4$ is the only solution.

If we plug in $x=2$ we get
$$\frac{2}{2}+2=2$$
or
$$3=2$$
which is not true.